# Show a stopping time is finite in probability

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Define a stopping time $\tau:= \min\{t:W_{t} = 1 \text{ or }  W_{t} = -1 \}$, I want to prove that $\mathbb{P}(\tau <  \infty ) = 1$, where $W_{t}$ is  a Brwonian motion. Here is my derivation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(\tau < t ) = \mathbb{P}(\tau < t | W_{t} = 1 \text{  before } W_{t} = -1)P(W_{t} = 1 \text{  before } W_{t} = -1) + \mathbb{P}(\tau < t | W_{t} = -1 \text{  before } W_{t} = 1)P(W_{t} = -1 \text{ 
 before } W_{t} = 1)
\end{aligned}
$$
Then,
$$
\mathbb{P}(\tau < t | W_{t} = 1 \text{  before } W_{t} = -1) = \mathbb{P}(\tau_{1} < t ) \\
\mathbb{P}(\tau < t | W_{t} = -1 \text{  before } W_{t} = 1) = \mathbb{P}(\tau_{-1} < t )
$$
where $\tau_{1}:= \min\{t:W_{t} = 1\}$  and  $\tau_{-1}:= \min\{t:W_{t} = -1\}$. Thus, we can only calculate

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(\tau_{1} < t ) &= \mathbb{P}(\tau_{1} < t , W_{t} > 1)  + \mathbb{P}(\tau_{1} < t , W_{t} < 1)  \\
&= 2  \mathbb{P}(\tau_{1} < t , W_{t} > 1){\text{ (By Reflection principle)}} \\
&=2\mathbb{P}(W_{t} > 1)
\end{aligned}
$$
For $\mathbb{P}(W_{t} > 1)$, it is very easy to calculate using  definition. Similarly to calculate $\mathbb{P}(\tau_{-1} < t ) $.

The last thing is  $P(W_{t} = 1 \text{  before } W_{t} = -1) $ which  is $\frac{1}{2}$ by the  martingale  of  $W_{t}$ and optional stopping theorem. Finally,  let $t$ goes to $\infty$, we can conclue that $\mathbb{P}(\tau <  \infty ) = 1$. Does that  right?